# Add a column with default value as a constant in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I'd like to alter an existing table to add a column which defines a large string as default in Postgres DB.

I have tried the following:

```
DO $$
declare PARAGRAPH character varying(4000):= 'Large text in here, around 4000 characters';
begin
    ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD COLUMN NOTES_TEXT character varying(4000) DEFAULT PARAGRAPH NOT NULL;
END $$;
```

Another way I found is the following:

```
DO $$
declare PARAGRAPH character varying(4000);
begin
    select 'Very large text goes in here.' into PARAGRAPH;
    
    ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD COLUMN NOTES_TEXT character varying(4000) DEFAULT PARAGRAPH NOT NULL;
END $$;
```

However, I am getting errors in both attempts related to the variable not recognized.

Do you know if this is possible in Postgres?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have `PARAGRAPH character varying(2000)` and then `'Large text in here, around 4000 characters';`, See the problem?

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver, not sure what could be the problem, I edited the character varying to be 4000, but really this was not the problem, even an empty string is failing.

Comment: what "errors" are you getting. Can you share the error message please. I don't think the problem is surfaced by your question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was this:

```
DO $$
declare PARAGRAPH character varying(4000);
begin
    PARAGRAPH := 'Very large text goes in here.';
    
    ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD COLUMN NOTES_TEXT character varying(4000) DEFAULT PARAGRAPH NOT NULL;
END $$;
ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD COLUMN NOTES_TEXT character varying(4000) DEFAULT PARAGRAPH NOT NULL"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement
```

The solution from here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
DO $$                                     
declare PARAGRAPH character varying(4000);
begin
    PARAGRAPH := 'Very large text goes in here.';
    
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE USERS ' ||
    'ADD COLUMN NOTES_TEXT character varying(4000) DEFAULT' ||quote_literal(PARAGRAPH) || 'NOT NULL';
END $$;

\d users
...
 notes_text      | character varying(4000) |           | not null | 'Very large text goes in here.'::character varying
```